# How to generate a JButton based on user input?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How to generate a `JButton` based on user input?

I want to create a Java Swing GUI program that allows a user to upload his/her pictures on a GUI. If the user selects multiple picture using a file chooser, the window will generate buttons that have the user's selected file. Just like when uploading pictures on facebook..

Also is there any other way to do this simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
File[] files = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

if ( files != null && files.length > 0) {
    for ( File file : files ) {
        layoutmanager.add(new JButton("Filename")); // Or anything else you want to do with the files/buttons
    }
}
```